# how to start a USSD session again after calling client API

Tags: c#, ussd

C# USSD menu - I have ended USSD session and calling the client API Then response from API comes back to USSD .Now I wanted to start a USSD session again after at that point.

```
[HandlesSessionTimeout]
        public async Task<UssdResponse> ProceedAirtime()
        {
           //started a ew thread
                    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await CallSubGSMAPI());
                //want to open session again after the above call completes
           //closing the session by retruning value to method
           return await Task.FromResult(Render("Please wait", null));
        }
```

Comment: Hi please [edit] your question and add the relevant code pieces.

Comment: It depends on the type of machine you are on the the interfaces you are using.  A USSD is a connection between cell phone devices.  So it depend if you have a mobile machine or a main frame.  Main Frames uses a GSM modem to send message but not receive.  To receive message you need to communicate through (receive) a Gateway.  So I need more info on the client API to help.